# Remove a loop to find existing numbers in database to one single query

Tags: php, mysql

I am sending an array of numbers separated by commans to server. Basically on server database I have a field that cotains numbers.Server side code checks which numbers are in database and send me the array of those numbers.

Following code is what I am using...

```
           public function already_user()
{
           $contacts=$this->input->post('contact');
           //$contacts is an array.

            $user=  explode(',',$contacts);
            foreach($user as $number)
{

            $data = array (
            'username' =>$number
            );
            $usernumber = $this->chat_model->get(array('username'=>$number)); // a simple query to datbase that check if number exists in database column or not.
              if(!$usernumber==""){
                  $value[]=$usernumber;

              }

           }
           echo json_encode($value);

           }
```

Only drawback about this code is , its extremely slow.... If i have 1000+ numbers it takes a minute.since its a loop Is there any way to fasten this up. Any single mysql query??

Comment: it is always poor database design to store an array in a single column in any database. MySQL can be a very powerful relational database when used correctly and a horrifically slow database when used incorrectly. I would suggest splitting the array out to a different table and relate each row to a user.

Comment: Prepare an `IN` query, or use `FIND_IN_SET()`.

Comment: There is NO Array stored in any column. There are number stored in one field. i-e phone number. Now i am sending an array of numbers to check that which numbers exist in database

Comment: @MuhammadUmar sorry I misunderstood the question.

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you just write a single query? Parse the string to get an array and query the table in a single go.

```
$contact_array = array_map('trim', explode(', ', $contacts));

$all_usernumbers = $this->chat_model->get(array('username IN'=> $contact_array));
```

which should (depending of what your `chat_model->get()` accepts), translate to:

```
SELECT  * FROM your_table WHERE username IN ('123', '345')
```

This is all pseudocode since I don't know what your `framework` accepts but the SQL query above should be valid.

Comment: can you make a mysql query please. ignore my code , I have a column in database named as "phone" and a string of numbers separated by commas converted to array $user=  explode(',',$contacts); That is what a want. a single query because a loop takes too much time

Comment: i have having trouble in concating the array with our query. My query is $query="SELECT * FROM `ofUser` WHERE username IN ".$contact_array; What should i do her